# Matching. Data simulation and estimation with MatchIt and Matching. How to retrieve true model?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, matching, economics

I am trying to simulate the sensitivity of [matching](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~estuart/propensityscoresoftware.html) versus regression (OLS) but I am doing something wrong somewhere because I cannot retrieve the true model using `matching`.

I am generating 3 variables: `x`, a background characteristic, `d` which is the Treatment variable (binary) and `y` outcome. `d` is associated with `x`. The idea of matching is that once conditioned on `x`, the treatment assignment generation process is as good as random. In the regression world, `x` is simply a control variable. I want to test how regression performs when there is region of non-common support (no treated above or below certain values) in the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Matching)
library(MatchIt)

N = 1000
# generate random variable normality dist #
x = rnorm(N, 0, 5)
```

This is how I generate an association between `x` and `d` (binary).

```
# generate Treatement associated with x, with different probailities after a certain threshold #
d = ifelse(x > 0.7, rbinom(0.7 * N, 1, 0.6) , rbinom( (1 - 0.7) * N, 1, 0.3) )
# beyond 0.7 the proba is 0.6 to receive treatment and below is 0.3 #
```

Seems correct to me, but if you have a better way to do it, let me know.

```
# adding a bit more randomness #
d[ sample(length(d), 100) ] <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)

# also adding a cut-off point for the treated #  
d[x < -10] <- 0
d[x > 10] <- 0
```

I am generating the effect of `d` using `ifelse`, seems correct to me, but I might be wrong.

```
# generate outcome y, w/ polyn relationship with x and a Treatment effect of 15 # sd == 10 #
y = x*1 + x^2 + rnorm(N, ifelse(d == 1, 15, 0), 10)

#
df = cbind(x,d,y) %>% as.data.frame()
# check out the "common support"
df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = factor(d) )) + geom_point()
#
```

The plot shows the way I want to model the 3 relationships. Note the cut-offs above and below 10 for the treated.

[image]

Now when I estimate the effect of `d` on `y` with OLS, the model with omitted variable and the misspecified model as expected give me an incorrect  estimate of `d`.

```
# omitted x #
lm(y ~ d, df) %>% summary()
# misspecification #
lm(y ~ d + x, df) %>% summary()
# true model #
```

While the correct specification gets me `15` (the true effect of `d`).

```
lm(y ~ d + poly(x,2), df) %>% summary()
# we correctly retrieve 15 #
```

Now my issue is to understand why I can't get to `15` (true effect of d) with the matching packages.

Using `MatchIt` package.

I tried with `mahalanobis` and a propensity score like this:

```
m1 = matchit(d ~ x, df, distance = 'mahalanobis', method = 'genetic')
m2a = matchit(d ~ x, df, distance = 'logit', method = 'genetic')
m2b = matchit(d ~ x + I(x^2), df, distance = 'logit', method = 'genetic')
```

Matching the data

```
mat1 = match.data(m1)
mat2a = match.data(m2a)
mat2b = match.data(m2b)

# OLS #
lm(y ~ d, mat1) %>% summary()
lm(y ~ d, mat2a) %>% summary()
lm(y ~ d, mat2b) %>% summary()
```

So here I do not retrieve the `15`. Why? Am I misinterpreting the results? 
I was under the impression that when doing `matching`, you did not have to model polynomial terms or/and interactions. Is that incorrect?

```
lm(y ~ d + poly(x,2), mat1) %>% summary()
lm(y ~ d + poly(x,2), mat2a) %>% summary()
lm(y ~ d + poly(x,2), mat2b) %>% summary()
```

Because I retrieve 15 if I include the `poly(x,2)` term here.

Using `Matching` package, I also get a completely different estimate

```
x1 = df$x
gl = glm(d ~ x + I(x^2), df, family = binomial)
x1 = gl$fitted.values

# I thought that it could be because OLS only gives ATE #
m0 = Match(Y = y, Tr = d, X = x1, estimand = 'ATE')
# but no 
m0$est
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important output of the matching procedure are the weights on the control observations. The weights are computed such that the distribution of the propensity score is similar in the treated and the control group (once the weights are applied).

In your case, this means (starting from your dgp and with your notations):

```
lm(y ~ d, mat1, weights = weights) %>% summary()
lm(y ~ d, mat2a, weights = weights) %>% summary()
lm(y ~ d, mat2b, weights = weights) %>% summary()
```

And here we are: `15` is back (or actually 14.9)!

Comment: very cool thank you. Makes sense! what about the `mahalanobis'?

Comment: It works in the same way for the mahalanobis, on my side. You mean `Matching::Match()` maybe, relating to your last point?